# Android Studio newly created folders not showing

Tags: android, xml

I am using Android Studio 2.1.1 (currently the most updated stable version).
I created new directory inside 'res' by name "values-21"
and it don't shows up.
But if I go to the physical location of 'res' on the hard drive I can see that its exist.
and of course I checked using **both Android and Project Files structure** but either way its not showing it.
I wanted to check where is the problem so I created another directory by name "menu", and the last one was shown.
just to be sure I tried to create the same directory again ("values-21") but Android studio didn't allowed it because this directory allready exist's.
any ideas how to fix it?

***Update*** - the solution is to create new directory using the **"Android resource Directory"** option and not by "Directory" option.

Answer (score 1):

all you values xml files stored in values, values-21, values-mdpi or other physical folder in AndroidStudio displayed in one res/values folder.

Comment: In the defualt created project there is already 2 different folders for values "values" and "values-w820dp" so what the different's between "values-21" and "values-w820dp"?. and besides if youre right how can I access that folder in order to create inside new files?

Comment: different between values-v21 and values-w820dp the next - values-v21 folder is used when device where you start you app have API version 21. resources folder values-w820dp is used when you app start on device where landscape dimension equal or more then 820dp widht.

Comment: when you create new resource - you right click on values folder then choose new then values resource file. there you can see directory name text field where you can set the name of folder of you resource.

Answer (score 1):

It will not show until you copy a XML file into values-21, android studio consider all values folders to be of same family and it shows only one folder and the files with post script of the family in which it lies.

[image]

Comment: so how can I technically copy files inside folder that I cannot access?

Comment: You just press control+v on the main values folder and android studio will ask for the destination family. Or you can also directly copy the files in the file explorer and Android Studio instantly refreshes the folder when you collapse and expand it.

Comment: you right, but I think that the simplest solution to my problem is listed in the Update of my question.

Comment: It is a pre-condition perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

copy some layout file from resource directory and through windows explorer paste in that the folder that you have created i.e `values-21` and now come back to android studio and check the folder should be there.

Happy coding

Comment: Tried it and it worked. but can you suggest a more simple solution, or maybe its a bug?

Comment: if you will look at the question update - clearly its not a bug.